# r mask for grep for finding the repeated words

Tags: r, regex

I just want find rows with the repeated word HALL (more than one time). For example, `"HALL #1 HALL #2 HALL #3"`. I tried to use

```
grepl("HALL{2,}", "HALL #1 HALL #2 HALL #3")
```

but `grepl` returned `FALSE`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `{2,}` means match characters right before it for two or more times. So if you want to match the `HALL` pattern, you need to put a parentheses around it and also it seems that you are not meaning to match `HALL` consecutively so you need to pad the pattern a little bit. The following should do the work:

```
grepl("(.*HALL.*){2,}", "HALL #1 HALL #2 HALL #3")
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `stringr`,

```
str_count("HALL #1 HALL #2 HALL #3", 'HALL')>1
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `(?:.*?HALL.*?){2,}`:

```
grepl("(?:.*?HALL.*?){2,}", "HALL #1 HALL #2 HALL #3")
#[1] TRUE
```

[Here is a breakdown](https://regex101.com/r/mQ7tM8/1) of the above regex.